# How can I convert a latching relay to two discrete momentary outputs?

Tags: latching-relay

I can find some questions that have some similarities to this one, but I think mine is different in the sense that I need to control two discrete outputs, one when the relay closes and one when it opens.

I have a device that I would like to control with a relay that can be controlled remotely (which I already have). Basically I would need to momentarily close a volt-free circuit with a 2k2 resistance when the relay closes and momentarily close the same circuit with a 6k2 resistance when it opens.

Here's a picture that might shed light on my clumsy description:

[image]

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @MichaelKaras I have tried a couple of approaches but come to the conclusion that my design skills are just not up to it ;-) I first thought I could to it with two 555 timers and an external power source and I spent a while with a simulation package that I downloaded. I am currently thinking that if I can't get any help then I'll have to resort to two non-latching relays but I'd prefer something a bit more elegant if possible (I have started building this design but it's a bit bulky). I did a module in elec. eng during my undergrad course and I am really wishing that I had paid attention, TBH!

Comment: @jamesmus So why not add your previous tries to the question? This reduces the probability that others might suggest options you already have evaluated.

Comment: @Ariser - Yes that makes sense, apologies. I suppose in the back of my mind was partly the thought that I didn't want to prejudice the answers and partly the feeling that I was a little embarrassed about failing to complete a solution having started a couple of times.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to get a couple of additional SPDT relays, one with a time delay, and switch them with your existing relay:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRmLEn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When RLY1 closes, RLY2 pulls in right away and puts R1 across the output circuit. After a time delay, RLY3 pulls in and opens the circuit again.

A similar thing happens when RLY1 opens, but involving R2 instead.

---

You can use a 555 to create the time delay, like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3wUEw.png)</sup>

When RLY1 is open, R3 discharges C2 through the coil of RLY2. This "triggers" the 555, so its output is high and the "discharge" pin is open.

WHen RLY1 closes, C2 starts to charge, and when it gets to 2/3 Vcc, the 555 output goes low, and the discharge pin turns on RLY3.

When RLY1 opens again, C2 discharges, and when it gets to 1/3 Vcc, the 555 triggers again, starting the cycle over.

The time delay is controlled by the combination of R3 and C2. The values shown will give you about 1.1 seconds.

If you prefer, you can use a 12V source and 12V relays. The 555 can handle either voltage.

Comment: Thanks @Dave Tweed. I was hoping to do it without relays but maybe it's the best solution.

Comment: Thanks for the extra circuit with the timer.